# Placing a div sibiling in the vertical center of another div

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, owl-carousel

I'm creating a slide on a site that uses bootstrap 4 and owl carousel 2. Do I need to put the navigation on the slide, how do this, see my code below:

NOTE: I need to make navigation within a container not to get 100% of the width of the window.

HTML

```
<section class="slide">
    <div class="owl-carousel">
        <div class="item"><img src="/img/laminas/lamina-01.jpg"></div>
        <div class="item"><img src="/img/laminas/lamina-01.jpg"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="nav-container"></div>
    </div>
</section>
```

JS

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    items:1,
    autoplay:true,
    autoplayHoverPause:true,
    nav:true,
    navText:['<div class="nav-slide"><i class="flaticon-arrows-1"></i></div>', '<div class="nav-slide"><i class="flaticon-arrows"></i></div>'],
    navContainer:'.nav-container'
})
```

Comment: can you post your css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<section class="slide">
    <div class="owl-carousel">
        <div class="item"><img src="/img/laminas/lamina-01.jpg"></div>
        <div class="item"><img src="/img/laminas/lamina-01.jpg"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide-content">
      <div class="container">
          <div class="nav-container"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
</section>

.slide {
  position: relative;
}
.slide .slide-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

This will place the navigation in the center of the slide. if you want it at the bottom adjust to suit

Comment: @Angelo Merlo Glad I was able to help :) would appreciate a vote up so people can see the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) css for this.  `justify-content: center` will align it horizontally, and `align-content: center` or `align-items: center` will center it vertically.

Answer (score 0):

Without your css, I'm guessing here a bit, but I put together a quick example to show how the navigation can be set to not to stretch 100% width;

http://jsfiddle.net/8qhfj6u2/

**HTML**

```
<div class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="item"><h4>1</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>2</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>3</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>4</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>5</h4></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="nav-container"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
  background: #ccc;
}

.owl-carousel .item {
    height: 10rem;
    background: #4DC7A0;
    padding: 1rem;
}
.container{
    height: 300px;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #000;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.nav-container{
    background: #fff;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
        loop:true,
        items:1,
        autoplay:true,
        autoplayHoverPause:true,
        nav:true,
        navText:['<div class="prev">Previous</div>','<div class="next">Next</div>'],
        navContainer:'.nav-container'
    })
});
```